# App Engine is sending duplicate requests (6 times +) to my Servlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

Am working on a web application where i have a servlet with service(request, response) method. Generally this method should get called once for every request that i send from my browser. But the app engine is invoking this method multiple times when i click on a link in my browser. Because of this behavior my servlet is invoking the internal logic multiple times which is not at all accepted to scale this application to 10000+ users.

BTW, this is not accidental and is been happening. I have tried all options provided in web.xml and appengine-web.xml file. But i don't see correct configuration to handle this.

Can anybody help me on this behavior with app engine. This is very important for our development.

Comment: check if your method is a datastore transactional one - if so transaction conflicts will cause automatic re-execution of the method (with no visible indication in the logs other than repeated execution), you'll need to adjust your logic to tolerate duplicate execution of the method (or re-arrange the logic to not leave room for conflicting transactions, but I guess this may be more difficult).

Comment: If you searched the web and SO, you probably noticed that no one else is complaining about such behavior while App Engine is being used by tens of thousands of developers for almost a decade. Which means that there is a 99.99% probability that this behavior is caused by your own code.

Comment: To get help on SO, you need to show concrete evidence. Are you determining this with a breakpoint? Logs? My guess would be that you're seeing this in the logs, and it's an artifact of the way long logs are concatenated, but without more info no one can help you.